# Matlab - finding solution for scaling a curve

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimum

Consider two curves, for example:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20];
y1 = [0 0 -0.3 -0.8 -1.1 -1 -0.5 1 1.1 1 -0.3 -0.8 -1.1 -1 -0.5 0.1 0.05 0 0 0];
y2 = [0 -0.2 -0.3 -0.8 -2 1 2.8 2.4 1.5 1.1 2.3 -0.4 -0.2 1 1.1 1.2 1.3 0.5 -0.1 0];
```

[image]

I'd like to write a generalized algorithm that takes in `x`, `y1`, and `y2`, and scales `y1` by a global scale factor, `f`, such that the new value of `y2-y1` is as close as possible to `0`. That is, `y2-f*y1` is as close to 0 as possible.

How can I do this?

Comment: This question is waaaaaaay too broad... there are various algorithms with different properties. Should the values be weighed or not? What about outliers? In general you'll need [**`fminsearch`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) function.

Comment: `fminsearch` and pass in `y1` and `y2` as parameters using an anonymous function

Comment: Values are not weighted. The math would simply work like I listed in the problem statement. I'm sure there are fancy ways of doing it but for the time being I'd like to keep it simple, just using the math I mentioned (ie, ignoring outliers).

Comment: You should define what you mean by "close" when you say "as close to 0 as possible". Minimum squares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
% Create a function that you want to minimize
func = @(f, y1, y2)abs(sum(y2 - f*y1));

% Your example data
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20];
y1 = [0 0 -0.3 -0.8 -1.1 -1 -0.5 1 1.1 1 -0.3 -0.8 -1.1 -1 -0.5 0.1 0.05 0 0 0];
y2 = [0 -0.2 -0.3 -0.8 -2 1 2.8 2.4 1.5 1.1 2.3 -0.4 -0.2 1 1.1 1.2 1.3 0.5 -0.1 0];

% Plot the before
figure()
plot(x, y2); hold all;
plot(x, y1)

% Find the optimum scale factor
f_start = 0; % May want a different starting point
f = fminsearch(@(f) func(f, y1, y2), f_start);
disp(['Scale factor = ' num2str(f)]) % print to the output 

% Plot the after (scaled data)
figure()
plot(x, y2); hold all;
plot(x, f*y1)
```

For more information see the docs on [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) and [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html?searchHighlight=fminsearch) (see example #2).

**EDIT**

Here is the output of the above script:

> Scale factor = -2.9398

Before [image: Before]

After [image: After]

As you can see the difference between the functions is minimized (area where y1 is greater than y2 is about the same as the area where y1 is less than y2). If you want the lines to match up as close as possible then you need to modify the minimization function like so:

```
func = @(f, y1, y2)sum(abs(y2 - f*y1));
```

I had to modify the test data for this case as it appears the data was already lined up optimally.

```
y1 = [0 0 -0.3 -0.8 -1.1 -1 -0.5 1 1.1 1 -0.3 -0.8 -1.1 -1 -0.5 0.1 0.05 0 0 0];
y2 = -2*y1 +1;
```

which gives the following output:

> Scale factor = -2.9091

Before [image]

After [image]

Comment: Why did you include the abs? I  tried testing it, looks like it found a scale factor of about -3, which doesn't seem right visually.

Comment: The goal is for y2-f*y1 to be as close to 0 as possible, not to be as low as possible (ie, a huge negative number, which the system is finding now)

Comment: I used `abs` so that it wouldn't find a huge negative number. Using `abs` makes the minimum zero.

Comment: I added some more info that I think addresses your concerns.